# woocommerce on order complete insert quantity data into custom database table

Tags: database, woocommerce, insert, orders

I need in woocommerce after successful Paypal payment and product status change to complete, to insert some info data about the order product e.g product quantity to one of my custom database tables.
what action/filter will do the job any example?

Answer (score 1):

After some testing I found solution with this hook

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_order_status_completed', 'check_quantity' );
function check_quantity($order_id) {

// order object (optional but handy)
$order = new WC_Order( $order_id );

if ( count( $order->get_items() ) > 0 ) {
foreach( $order->get_items() as $item ) {

// for all products if ( $item['id'] > 0 ) {
if ( $item['id'] == 8 ) {
$quantity=$item['qty'];
add_qty($quantity);

   }
  }
 }
}
```